# Cannot add my scoretext to script in gamecontrol in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I am new to unity and I am trying to make a flappy bird as a project but I am stuck in one place.
I created a game control script and added game over text and it worked fine, but when I tried to add to score text to a different script, it didn't work.
It's hard to explain in words, here's a pic and script.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLsKv.png

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static GameControl instance;
        public GameObject gameOverText;
        public Text scoreText;
        public bool gameOver = false;
        public float scrollingSpeed = -1.5f;    

        private int score = 0;

        void Awake()
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = this;
            }
            else if(instance != this)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if(gameOver == true && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
               SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
            }
        }
        
        public void PlayerScored()
        {
            if (gameOver)
            {
                return;
            }
            score++;
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
        }
    
        public void PlayerDied()
        {
            gameOverText.SetActive(true);
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gameobject you are trying to drag into the `Text` slot doesn't have a **"Text"** component which looks like this:
[image]

Add this component to your gameobject.

---

If the gameobject already has the **"Text"** component, there must be some other problem which is that you don't have "Event System" in your scene which probably got deleted accidentally. Right click on your hierarchy and add **"Event System"**.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I got what went wrong, I used text-mesh pro which I don't know why didn't work.